# Setting up Keycloak with Kong v5.1

Tags: api-gateway, keycloak

I found a [tutorial](https://dev.to/robincher/securing-your-site-via-oidc-powered-by-kong-and-keycloak-2ccc) how to setup kong with two open source plugins to get keycloak working with kong, but unfortunately it is 2 years old and I ran in troubles.

Most of the steps still worked and I was able to install the plugin versions in the tutorial via `luarocks`. unfortunately, the kong did not restart after configuring it to work with the plugins:

`plungins = bundeld,oidc,jwt-keycloak`

running in the error, that the `kong.plugins.base_plugin` cannot be found:

```
Error: /usr/local/share/lua/5.1/kong/tools/utils.lua:708: error loading module 'kong.plugins.oidc.handler':
/usr/local/share/lua/5.1/kong/plugins/oidc/handler.lua:1: module 'kong.plugins.base_plugin' not found:No LuaRocks module found for kong.plugins.base_plugin
    no field package.preload['kong.plugins.base_plugin']
```

**What I tried**

- I tried to install a `base_plugin` but lua does not find any.
- I was googling a lot, but did't quite found the same issue.

Well, I am quite stuck and was wondering if there is an other way (maybe directly with the oAuth plugin?), or how I can fix this issue. Also I don't really know how debug that issue and am happy for ideas!

Answer (score 1):

The root cause is BasePlugin is deprecated and removed from kong 3.x,see it [here](https://docs.konghq.com/gateway/latest/plugin-development/custom-logic/#migrating-from-baseplugin-module).The jwt-keycloak plugin imported BasePlugin in handler.lua, so you have to do the migration by yourself,it's easy,just fork its repo,change code,install it from source in Dockerfile。

Comment: Please share with me the details about: "change code" of your answer.

Comment: https://github.com/zjjfly/kong-plugin-jwt-keycloak, this is my repo forked from gbbirkisson's repo，you can find my changes in commit history